# Server 2012 IIS site on different drive

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to get IIS 8 on a brand new Server 2012 up and running to run a .net 4.5 app and I can't get it to work across drives

```
Error: 500.19
Module
   IIS Web Core 
Notification
   Unknown 
Handler
   Not yet determined 
Error Code
   0x80070005 
Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions  
Config File
   \\?\D:\callsheet-test\web.config
```

The current site is just a single file index.html.

If I copy the folder to anywhere on c:  like c:\callsheet-test\ or c:\inetpub\callsheet-test it works perfectly once I change the target location in IIS 8 (site > basic settings).

It doesn't matter if there is an web.config file as a complex mvc/webforms app gives the same error.

I have tried copying the file with permissions and even thought the permissions seem to match for all users. I am still getting this error.

I have deleted the partition and and recreated it as a mount point c:\mount and the same issue happens. Copy the files to c:\notamount and they work fine.

This server is running on a VMware server.  Windows 2012 x64 Standard.

Comment: They're calling it a bug on the IIS forums here: [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1193777.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further investigation of the problem (via link in my comment above), I've found a **workaround** via [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprovirt/thread/20da7ff7-05a7-4085-8e67-258f11755f3d/): change the Group Policy value of "Audit Removable Storage" from "Not Configured" to "No Auditing" and reboot. Bizarre I know. This setting is in Windows Settings/Security Settings/Advanced Audit Policy Configuration/System Audit Policies/Object Access.

Even though we're using VMWare and not Hyper-V this workaround still worked for me. Hopefully Microsoft can provide a answer.

Comment: Also strongly related http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserver8gen/thread/9807a799-bea3-46ad-92a5-732779135f98

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error and the solution was similar.  I had installed Sql Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 and it was at this time that I noticed IIS worker processes running from the system C: drive were unable to access configuration files on the E: drive.  The site could only be loaded when on the C: drive, despite all the necessary NTFS permissions being granted through IIS_IUSRS, IUSR, Users and/or even the specific AppPool itself.  This became evident when IIS couldn't access the E: drive even when running the AppPool (.NET 4.5) using an admin account other than  the ApplicationPoolIdentity account (IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5 in this context - verified in procexp.exe).  Installing Sql Server 2012 was throwing errors during installation and required enabling auditing for object access among other settings.

Solution:

1. Run -> secpol.msc
2. Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy
3. Change "Audit Object Access" policy to "No Auditing"

Hopefully, this background helps ease someone's headache.  :-)